# iPhone Simulator vs. Main Storyboard Preview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have many layout constraints for a particular app, and in the main.storyboard (preview) the apps look a little bit off, but when I run them in the simulator they look how I want them.  So there is disconnect between the two.

I saw the question answered that fixing the constraint warnings would then make the two appear identical.

However, I do not want to try to fix these warnings.  A lot of time went into finally figuring how to lay all this out, and I'm worried fixing these (38) constraint errors will screw everything up.

My question is...with the disparity between the preview and the actual device simulation, which one will actually appear if the app is run on a real device?  I would assume the one showing in simulation, but I'm really not sure.  Is it safe to ignore the errors and the strange main.storyboard (preview) layout it shows me and go with the simulation?  It looks how I want it for each simulated device, so I'm weary of changing anything now.  Thank you!

Comment: No, just because it happened to look OK on the simulator does not mean you should ignore the warnings. Those warnings are there for a reason, so fix the underlying problems.

Comment: I would think the simulator is accurate.  After all, what's the point of it if it won't simulate correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, Xcode has some problems in storyboard. If you have a constraint which makes a view becomes visually invisible, you will get a warning about this constraint. You can quickly fix it by clicking the warning icon BUT if you close you project and reopen it again, the warning will be there.

The final result should be the UI shown in simulator instead of interface builder or storyboard.

Comment: I don't really have anything that will become invisible as each item I've constrained is there.  I can't see any alternative ways to layout what I have without having some errors there.  I've tried doing it multiple times and the errors mostly say the frame will be one unit off to the left or right, which is fine.  A few are conflicting, but I'm afraid those might screw something up if I try to delete them.  Not sure if this has anything to do with me using an iPhone 4 inch in the storyboard because it's small and easy to work with instead of the general view controller.

Comment: Invisible item is one of the possibilities only. If you get a red error instead of yellow warning, your constraints must have conflict. Is there any error message shown in console when you run the app in simulator?

Comment: Yes, there are many of them.  They tell me that some of the constraints are probably ones I don't want, and then provide a list of them.  But I run the simulator and they all look good, so I would think therefore I would actually want them?  Not sure how to rid of those errors mentioned earlier about the frame being one unit off and such, that just comes up when I add the constraint and nothing I can do about it.  I just don't want the app to appear fine here then actually in a downloadable app have it go bonkers on me.

Comment: Normally, there are two ways to fix this.

Comment: If you have changed the constraint constant programmatically, the high possibility of the error is that when you change the constraint value such as height, other views related to this constraint do not have enough space to show. In this case, you can comment out the line you change the constraint to see whether the error message is still here. The second way is that you can use divide and conquer to remove half of the constraint in the view to see which constraint makes the error message. Although this approach is quite time consuming, it is the best way to figure out the error.

Comment: Well the only programming I do with anything is to get the height of a label or something AFTER the new layout is shown with the constraints active, and change the text size in that label to scale nicely.  There's plenty of room in the labels so I don't know if that's the issue.  But not sure how to fix the errors that tell me something will horizontally show in the view controller as 40 but will display at 42.  Thanks for that?  But the only way to rid of that seems to delete that constraint...which will ruin my layout completely.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as solved.  A lot of my issues came from me not updating the frames, and the rest seemed to get solved once I had fixed an issue where one cell was a unit larger than the others, and I selected all of them to be the same height.  once I changed that and updated the frames, it looks nice.  I'll go ahead and let this question be, but if I think (if I'm correct) if I've got constraints set, then resize or move something, I'll have to update frames and constraints to see it visually.  Probably why the preview didn't look exact.  Thank you!